# Trying to resolve a missing dependency from multiple repositories with Maven

Tags: java, maven

We have an internal main repository and multiple sub repositories.  There are thirdparty libraries in one repository but may not be in another.  How do you configure maven to pull from "multiple" repositories.  For example, if I get an error like the one below, I usually end up changing the mirrorof to point to repository where the library is located but one by one.  It would be nice for my configuration to just pull from the library where it is missing.  Here is the configuration I have been changing in the settings.xml.  I was also trying to avoid project level changes in the pom.xml.

```
Error:

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project shared-library: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.smarts:smarts-shared-library:jar:1.0.0: Could not find artifact com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.5.2 in group (http://lxnexus.internal.com:8081/repository/legacy/) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, in a company you run your own Nexus/Artifactory server. In it, you define all desired repositories and one repository group (virtual repository) that bundles all of them. Then you can use that as a mirror in your `settings.xml`.

If you don't have that, don't define a mirror setting, but list all the desired repositories in the `<repositories>` section of the `settings.xml`.